# Can a Samsung Galaxy Previal be used as a test device for Android development?

Tags: android

I have been researching the Samsung Galaxy Prevail for Android development. This phone is meant to be used on the Boost network.

Will the phone be usable as a test device if it is never activated on the carrier's network? Will the device be able to connect to the internet through WiFi if it is never activated?

What is to stop someone from buying the device and using it as a glorified MP3 player?

http://reviews.cnet.com/smartphones/samsung-galaxy-prevail-boost/4505-6452_7-34629355.html#reviewPage1

[http://www.amazon.com/Boost-Mobile-BMSAMM820/dp/B004Z7HYUI/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1312915398&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004Z7HYUI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the phone be usable as a test device if it is never activated on
>   the carrier's network?

Yes.  I have a Nexus S that's never been activated which I use for development.

> Will the device be able to connect to the internet through WiFi if it
>   is never activated?

Yes.

> What is to stop someone from buying the device and using it as a
>   glorified MP3 player?

Nothing, really.

**Edit:** If you're simply looking for a real phone to develop on, you might want to scrounge around on eBay and look for people who have upgraded, and no longer need their phones.  As long as they have been cleanly removed from the carrier's network, they should work just fine.  Could be a good way to pick up a cheap phone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me what it means for a phone to have a bad ESN? I have seen some used Droid phones on eBay that are cheaper than a new Galaxy Prevail.

Comment: A bad ESN means that the phone was reported lost, stolen, or still attached to an account (most likely with an un-paid balance).  Even if you don't plan on activating it, I'd look for one with a clear ESN.